# Bug? Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]?

Tags: java, maven, akka

As per [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html#akka-testkit), under (Expecting Log Messages),

> Be sure to exchange the default logger with the TestEventListener in
>   your application.conf to enable this function: akka.loggers =
>   [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]

So, this works well when I put it in *application.conf*. My test work well

```
@Test
public void testActorForNonExistentLocation() throws Exception {
  final Map<String, String> configValues = Collections.singletonMap("tenant.assetsLocation",
                                                                    "/non/existentLocation");
  final Config config = mergeConfig(configValues);
  System.out.println(config.getList("akka.loggers"));

  new JavaTestKit(system) {{
    assertEquals("system", system.name());

    final Props props = TenantMonitorActor.props(config);
    final ActorRef supervisor = system.actorOf(props, "supervisor");
    new EventFilter<Void>(DiskException.class) {

      @Override
      protected Void run() {
        supervisor.tell(new TenantMonitorMessage(), supervisor);
        return null;
      }
    }.from("akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor").occurrences(1).exec();

  }};
}
```

Now when I try to run my application

```
public class Main {
  private Main() {
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
    final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(config.getString("ec.name"));
    setUpMonitoring(actorSystem, config);
  }

  private static void setUpMonitoring(final ActorSystem system, final Config config) {
    final ActorRef tenantMonitorRef = system.actorOf(TenantMonitorActor.props(config),
                                                     "tenantMonitor");
    tenantMonitorRef.tell(new TenantMonitorMessage(), tenantMonitorRef);
  }
}
```

I see errors as

```
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.testkit.TestEventListener] due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:116)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:115)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:115)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:110)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:728)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:727)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.startDefaultLoggers(Logging.scala:110)
    at akka.event.EventStream.startDefaultLoggers(EventStream.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:622)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:619)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:633)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:57)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.testkit.TestEventListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:113)
    ... 24 more
Exception in thread "main" akka.ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to [akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.testkit.TestEventListener] due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.testkit.TestEventListener]]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.startDefaultLoggers(Logging.scala:144)
    at akka.event.EventStream.startDefaultLoggers(EventStream.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:622)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:619)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:633)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:57)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

My *application.conf* looks like

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
  loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
}

ec {
  name = "Connector"
}

tenant {
  assetsLocation: /Users
}

monitoring {
  tenant.disk.schedule.seconds: 2
  tenant.disk.threshold.percent: 80
}
```

and I have the dependency installed as well

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${akka-actor_2.11.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${akka-testkit_2.11.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and with versions

```
<akka-actor_2.11.version>2.3.9</akka-actor_2.11.version>
<akka-testkit_2.11.version>2.3.10</akka-testkit_2.11.version>
```

*Where is bug/inconsistency?*

This *may not* be a bug at all and difference in understanding.

We use [maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to decide which dependencies should be available and when. Usually with tests, we use `<scope>test</scope>` to make the dependency available only in test and not in final application jar when bundled.

Now if we make use of this kind of tests(Expecting Log Messages), we need to remove `<scope>test</scope>` to let the application run correctly and tests pass at the same time. Which means that that dependency akka-testkit need to be present in the final jar as well since *application.conf* needs it to load `akka.testkit.TestEventListener`.

This if all sounds correct, couples production and test code together and is required in current setup.

Again, I may have missed something very basic here, but the only way I could run the application and let the test pass is by combining  the dependencies `akka-actor` and `akka-testkit together`.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You may need to add the akka-slf4j dependency.

Comment: Thanks, but adding `akka-slf4j` did not help resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an application.conf in your test resources:

```
src/test/resources/application.conf
```

Contents could look like:

```
include "../../main/resources/application"

akka.loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
```

This application.conf will be loaded only during tests, so you can scope your `akka-testkit` dependency to test only.